WW2 comedy where fascist soldiers don't want to fight with Americans and mock firefights
I've recently seen a part of this movie on my TV, but can't figure the name or find anything on Google.
It's a World War II comedy about Italian (or Greek) village or small town where fascist soldiers refuse to fight Americans when they arrive and they camp together in peace untill someone from command start poking arround and then they stage mock firefights, so they don't get redeployed to front lines.
I believe it's from the '50s.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Probably What Did You Do in the War, Daddy?

A by-the-book captain is ordered to capture a strategic village in
  Italy. The Italian soldiers are willing to surrender, if they can have
  a festival first. The lieutenant convinces the captain this is the
  only way. Because of aerial reconnaissance, they must look like they
  are fighting. To sort this out an intelligence officer is sent in.


